# How to speed up read write base64 encoded gzipped large files in Java

Tags: java, io, compression, bigdata

The task is to compress/decompress very large data **> 2G**, which cannot be hold by a single String or ByteArray. My solution is to write compressed/decompressed data chunk by chunk into a file. It works, but not fast enough.

*Compress*: plain text file -> gzip -> base64 encode -> compressed file
*Decompress*: compressed file -> base64 decode -> gunzip -> plain text file

Test result on laptop, with 16G memory.

```
Created compressed file, takes 571346 millis
Created decompressed file, takes 378441 millis
```

Code block

```
public static void compress(final InputStream inputStream, final Path outputFile) throws IOException {
    try (final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toString());
        final OutputStream base64Output = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(outputStream);
        final GzipCompressorOutputStream gzipOutput = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(base64Output);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

      reader.lines().forEach(line -> {
        try {
          gzipOutput.write(line.getBytes());
          gzipOutput.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
    }
  }

public static void decompress(final InputStream inputStream, final Path outputFile) throws IOException {
  try (final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toString());
      final GzipCompressorInputStream gzipStream = new GzipCompressorInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().wrap(inputStream));
      final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzipStream))) {

    reader.lines().forEach(line -> {
      try {
        outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
        outputStream.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
      } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I tried to do batch write when sending data to file, didn't see much improvement.

```
# batch write
public static void compress(final InputStream inputStream, final Path outputFile) throws IOException {
  try (final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toString());
      final OutputStream base64Output = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(outputStream);
      final GzipCompressorOutputStream gzipOutput = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(base64Output);
      final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    final int chunkSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 1000;

    String line;
    int counter = 0;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      counter++;
      stringBuilder.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      if(counter >= chunkSize) {
        gzipOutput.write(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
        counter = 0;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      }
    }

    if (counter > 0) {
      gzipOutput.write(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
    }
  }
}
```

#### Question

1. Looking for suggestion on how to speed up the overall process
2. What will be the bottlenecks?

#### 10/2/2019 update

I did some more tests, the results show that base64 encoding is the bottleneck.

```
public static void compress(final InputStream inputStream, final Path outputFile) throws IOException {
  try (final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toString());
       final OutputStream base64Output = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(outputStream);
       final GzipCompressorOutputStream gzipOutput = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(base64Output)) {

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
      gzipOutput.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
  }
}
```

- 2.2G test file, with 21.5 Million lines
- Copy file only: ~ 2 seconds
- Gzip file only: ~ 12 seconds
- Gzip + base64: ~ 500 seconds

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't expected the base64 part to be *that* slow

Comment: @harold that's true, the result is surprising! As I read another article on base64 performance, http://java-performance.info/base64-encoding-and-decoding-performance/,  the result shows that, it takes 0.45s to encode 200MB, from byte[] to byte[]. In our case, 2.2G, would take about 5s. It must be something else that makes it slow, which I cannot figure out so far.

Comment: I saw that Base64 would be slow if the stream that writes to it does so byte-by-byte (or other small pieces) because the converter likes to convert 3 bytes at the time, but it seems like the gzip stream doesn't even do that (eventually it goes through PendingBuffer), so I still can't explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: never default the charset, as that is not portable.

```
String s = ...;
byte[] b = ...;
b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

For compression of text do not involve a Reader, as that converts bytes given some charset into a String (holding Unicode), and again a conversion back. Also a String's char requires 2 bytes (UTF-16) as opposed to 1 byte for basic ASCII symbols.

Base64 converts binary to an alphabet of 64 ASCII symbols, requiring 4/3 the space. Do not do that other when the data must be transmitted packed in XML or such.

Large files can be (de)compressed.

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 64;
Path textFile = Paths.get(".... .txt");
Path gzFile = textFile.resolveSibling(textFile.getFileName().toString() + ".gz");

try (OutputStream out = new GzipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(gzFile), BUFFER_SIZE))) {
    Files.copy(textFile, out);
}

try (InputStream in = new GzipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(gzFile), BUFFER_SIZE))) {
    Files.copy(in, textFile);
}
```

Often the optional parameter BUFFER_SIZE is overlooked, which might degrade performance.

`copy` can have additional parameters for handling file clashes.

Answer (score 2):

Large files will always take some time, but I see two significant opportunities:

1. Remove the Base64 step if possible. It makes the file bigger, and bigger data costs more time to read/write. There is also the cost of base64 conversion itself.
2. Don't use *line* based IO. Actually don't use strings at all. Searching for line breaks and converting the data between plain bytes and `string` objects costs time, and it is not useful here: the work is undone and the fact that the data was in the form of a *line* is never really used, it's just an arbitrary way to chop up the data.

For a faster stream-to-stream copy, you could use for example [IOUtils.copy(in, out)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) (which is also in Apache Commons which it looks like you are using already), or else implement a similar strategy yourself: reading a block of data into a `byte[]` (several KB, not something tiny) and then writing it out to the output stream, until the input has all been read.